# How to assign a firebase uid to a session in bigquery?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create query sessions in firebase functions using node.js so I can monitor a users querying activity in bigquery. I was going to assigned the authed uid from firebase passed through the realtime db ref in firebase functions as a label in a bigquery job to find sessions by uid, however this doesn't work as labels must only have lowercase values.

Ultimately, I'm having a hard time designing a system where I deploy a job from firebase functions and identifying which user deployed that query.

I've tried using the firebase uid as a label for a job. Does not work because of label rules